# multiple item xml parsin in android

Tags: android, xml

My XML is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<menu>
<item>
    <id>1</id> 

    <name>Margherita</name>
    <cost>
        <p>155</p>
        <p>255</p>
        <p>355</p>
        <p>455</p>
    </cost>
    <description>Single cheese topping</description>
</item> 
<item>
    <id>2</id>    
    <name>Double Cheese Margherita</name>
    <cost>
        <p>900</p>
        <p>155</p>
    </cost>
    <description>Loaded with Extra Cheese</description>
</item> 
<item>
    <id>3</id>    
    <name>Fresh Veggie</name>
    <cost>
        <p>335</p>
    </cost>
    <description>Oninon and Crisp capsicum</description>
</item>
```

in cost tag I have other tags
I'm trying to parsing the xml with this:

```
    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
    // looping through all item nodes <item>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
        map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
        map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));



        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        menuItems.add(map);
    }
```

I want to access to the child nodes, which here is  and add another loop to access to all

values
How to get access to childern nodes ?!

Answer (score 0):

Your `item`s are already stored in that list, you can get an element like this:

```
HashMap item = menuItems.get(0); // get the first item
```

Or you can loop through all elements in your list:

```
for (HashMap item: menuItems) {
    // do something
}
```

Now you might wonder how you would access it's properties, you can use a HashMap like this:

```
String name = item.get(KEY_NAME);
```

Comment: No that's not my question,

Comment: I want to access to the child nodes, which here is <cost> and add another loop to access to all <p> values